# Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP) -HTML

Tags: html, amp-html

I'm new to AMP and I want to apply it to the site I'm working on, I was looking at the AMP documentation and I have problems when linking the html page with the amp page, I do not know if it's because I'm working locally, when I put in the browser the path of the amp page if it loads but when I do the linking between html and amp it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a standard HTML page and an AMP version of the same page, you need to place a reference to the AMP version from the head of the HTML page.  [Documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/spec#amp-document-discovery).

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">
```

The AMP version needs to have a reference back to the standard HTML version. This is done with a canonical tag, again this should be placed in the head of the HTML.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/canonical/document.html">
```

If your users land on the standard HTML version, their browser's won't automatically redirect them to the AMP version. This would force the browser to download the page twice and defeats the object of AMP, which is to speed up page load times.

Instead, when Google or other search engines crawl your site. They will hopefully see that you have an AMP version available and direct users to the URL of the AMP version.

This is why the AMP version does not load when you open the standard page.

Hope this helps.